# rowbind elements of list into pandas data frame by grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering what is the pythonic way of achieving the following:
Given a list of list:

```
l = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6],[7, 8]]
```

I would like to create a list of pandas data frames where the first pandas data frame is a row bind of the first two elements in `l` and the second a row bind of the last two elements:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(l[:2]))
>>> df1
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

and

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(l[2:]))
>>> df2
   0  1
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

In my problem I have a very long list and I know the grouping, i.e. the first k elements of the list `l` should be rowbinded to form the first df. How can this be achieved in a python friendly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them in `dict` like

```
In [586]: s = pd.Series(l)

In [587]: k = 2

In [588]: df = {k:pd.DataFrame(g.values.tolist()) for k, g in s.groupby(s.index//k)}

In [589]: df[0]
Out[589]:
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [590]: df[1]
Out[590]:
   0  1
0  5  6
1  7  8
```